Что лучше учить первым? Java Swing или JavaFX?
Я учу язык Java полностью самостоятельно, поэтому, какого-либо плана обучения у меня нету. И недавно у меня в голове возникла идея выучить JavaFX, но так как Java Swing я знаю частично, я задался вопросом: стоит ли мне доучить Java Swing и уже потом переходить к JavaFX, или же лучше сначала выучить JavaFX, а потом Java Swing. Просто я прочитал в интернете, что JavaFX гораздо новее, чем Java Swing, поэтому и возникли сомнения!

Обе библиотеки предназначены для создания GUI. JavaFX новее, современнее. Сейчас большество GUI java apps используют JavaFX, поэтому я бы сосридоточился на нем.

Хорошо, спасибо за совет!

Мой путь был такой: сначала swing, потом javaFX, сейчас spring. И если бы можно было написать себе письмо в прошлое, оно было бы таким "учи spring"! :)
